# MVC 4 : Javascript and CSS disabled on RedirectToAction

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a login page that will redirect to home page when logged in successful. However, when logged in successfully the javascript and css of the home page are disabled or is not applied to the page. The scripts and stylesheets are defined in the layout. Did i miss somehting here?

Additional Info:

I modified the RouteConfig:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
           name: "UserLogin",
           url: "{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "UserLogin" });

        routes.MapRoute(
         name: "CompanyList",
         url: "{controller}/{action}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Company", action = "List" });
```

The login page's script and stylesheets are fine but the Company List's page is messed up. But if i remove the login page from the routing config the Company List's page is fine. There are no errors whatsoever that i encountered.

Comment: Are there any errors on retrieving the javascript/stylesheets from the server? e.g. not status 200.

Comment: Make sure the user can access the folders the scrips and css are in.  What browser is this in?  What does the Network profile show in the dev tools for the browser?